# State space representation of VECM-GARCH

Tags: time-series, matlab, garch, kalman-filter, vector-error-correction-model

Can someone help me write a state-space representation for the VECM-GARCH model to estimate the time-varying parameters using Kalman Filtering in Matlab? I am struggling with specifying the GARCH specification for the error term in Matlab.

Comment: Is the problem in VECM or GARCH? Do you need the VECM, the GARCH, or the VECM-GARCH state-space representation?

Comment: I need the VECM GARCH state-space representation.

Comment: Is your problem conceptual or programming? Do you have the equations and are struggling to implement them or do you need to derive the equations first?

Comment: It's programming. I have run an OLS model and extracted the residuals as an error correction term. Now, I need to run VECM model with GARCH (1,1) error term and estimate time varying parameter ```$\alpha$ ``` using Kalman filter.I am struggling with the coding for this.

Comment: But do you have the mathematical formulas ready? If so, consider sharing them in your post, and maybe someone can help you code them in Matlab. Note, however, that such a question is actually off-topic. The on-topic part is the equations, but the specific implementation in Matlab is off-topic.

Comment: So, I am sorry for not being clear with the question. I am struggling with writing the model equations/ mathematical formulas. Once I know how to derive the formulas, I can work out the code.